# Python Azure Function: blobclient.upload_blob authorization failure

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-sdk-python

I have a python azure function that triggers on queue message and uploads a json to blob storage. I am getting authentication errors on blob.client using storage account SAS URL and SAS token, as well as storage account connection string

**function code:  the # symbol used as I was swapping between blobclients instances**

```
import json
import requests
import azure.functions as func
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient

def main(msg: func.QueueMessage) -> None:
             queuedata =  msg.get_body().decode('utf-8')
             data = json.loads(queuedata)
             url = data['data']['url']

             r = requests.get(url)
             data = r.text


             s1, s2 = (data.split(sep=';', maxsplit=1))
             s1 = ''.join(s1.split())

             dict1 = json.loads(s1)
             dict1 = json.loads(s2)
             mergedJson = {**dict1, **dict1}


             #connectionstring = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=XXXXXX;AccountKey=XXXXXXXX/Jm4OPgSzWOju5hD/+XA4QXXXXXXfNEbUxuO9WoUQ7xn91cE3qlQeqRoHJx3SrJ+bdln9Q==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"

             sas_url = 'https://XXXXX.blob.core.windows.net/?sv=2019-10-10&ss=bq&srt=c&sp=rwdlacupx&se=2020-06-13T04:48:27Z&st=2020-06-12T20:48:27Z&spr=https&sig=1j2a6pQUFLI1B71D8oRoALHYgpF82pMiXbvrdZCY7gk%3D'
             sas_token = '?sv=XXXXXXXXXX-10-10&ss=XXXXX&XXX=c&sp=rwdlacupx&se=2020-06-13T04:48:27Z&st=2020-06-12T20:48:27Z&spr=https&sig=1j2a6pQUFLI1B71D8oRoALHYgpF82pMiXbvrdZCY7gk%3D'


             filename = dictA['FormId'] + '.json'
             #blob_client = BlobClient.from_connection_string(conn_str= connectionstring,  container_name='json', content_type='application/json', blob_name= filename)
             #blob_client.upload_blob(mergedJson, blob_type='BlockBlob')

             blob_client2 = BlobClient(account_url= sas_url, credential= sas_token, container_name='json', blob_name= filename, content_type='application/json')
             blob_client2.upload_blob(mergedJson, blob_type='BlockBlob')
```

**On connectionstring error using BlobClient.from_connection_string(conn_str, container_name, blob_name, snapshot=None, credential=None, **kwargs):**

Result: Failure Exception: ClientAuthenticationError: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. RequestId:cdccbb2e-e01e-0007-6cfd-40c024000000 Time:2020-06-12T21:09:22.1504720Z ErrorCode:AuthenticationFailed Error:None AuthenticationErrorDetail:The MAC signature found in the HTTP request 'n+oKBbFHSn12Nhw3SIQk4OxUGLaxQRc32mh93GWEisM=' is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign: 'PUT 302 application/octet-stream * x-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob x-ms-client-request-id:fcba350c-acf0-11ea-b094-0242ac100105 x-ms-date:Fri, 12 Jun 2020 21:09:22 GMT x-ms-version:2019-07-07 /dmgenhwr/json/C1234567.json'. Stack: File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.7/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 315, in _handle__invocation_request self.**run_sync_func, invocation_id, fi.func, args) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs) File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.7/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 434, in __run_sync_func return func(**params) File "/home/site/wwwroot/TextQueue/__init**.py", line 32, in main blob_client.upload_blob(mergedJson, blob_type='BlockBlob') File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/azure/core/tracing/decorator.py", line 83, in wrapper_use_tracer return func(*args, **kwargs) File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_blob_client.py", line 496, in upload_blob return upload_block_blob(**options) File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_upload_helpers.py", line 153, in upload_block_blob process_storage_error(error) File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_shared/response_handlers.py", line 147, in process_storage_error raise error

**on SAS URL and SAS token error using BlobClient(account_url, container_name, blob_name, snapshot=None, credential=None, **kwargs):**

Result: Failure Exception: HttpResponseError: This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this resource type. RequestId:62bb329f-b01e-0036-19fb-409bf3000000 Time:2020-06-12T20:56:14.5723115Z ErrorCode:AuthorizationResourceTypeMismatch Error:None Stack: File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.7/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 315, in _handle__invocation_request self.**run_sync_func, invocation_id, fi.func, args) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs) File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.7/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 434, in __run_sync_func return func(**params) File "/home/site/wwwroot/TextQueue/__init**.py", line 35, in main blob_client2.upload_blob(mergedJson, blob_type='BlockBlob') File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/azure/core/tracing/decorator.py", line 83, in wrapper_use_tracer return func(*args, **kwargs) File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_blob_client.py", line 496, in upload_blob return upload_block_blob(**options) File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_upload_helpers.py", line 153, in upload_block_blob process_storage_error(error) File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_shared/response_handlers.py", line 147, in process_storage_error raise error

I have referenced [azure storage BlobClient class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python)

Does this function require an Http action method for the PUT? I do not see that referenced in the azure sdk for python.  Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Following the guide from [Use the Azure libraries with Azure Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/azure-sdk-example-storage-use?tabs=cmd) I added azure-identity and followed setup for authentication on the service principle "4a: Use blob storage with authentication"

The key was to grant permission to the blob container for the service principle.

My first attempt was to use guidance from "4b: Use blob storage with a connection string" but I had no success.  Using service principle and following the directions from
[system assigned managed identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview) and [authorize access to blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad)
appears to have resolved this issue.

Now encountering "Runtime dependency of PyGObject is missing" - hoop jumping to setup an python azure function is fun NOT.